# How to rename using (ns (:require :refer))

Tags: variables, import, clojure, namespaces

My understanding is that it is recommended now to use 
`require :refer` instead of `use` in the `ns` macro.  For example, do:

```
(ns example.core 
  (:require [clj-json.core :refer [parse-string]]))
```

instead of

```
(ns example.core 
  (:use [clj-json.core :only [parse-string]]))
```

What is the recommended way to deal with `:rename` which `use` supports?
Specifically, let's say I want to `require`
clojure.data.zip and rename the `ancestors` and `descendants` functions which conflict with clojure.core.

In other words I'd like to know the `require` equivalent for

```
(:use 
  [clojure.data.zip :rename {ancestors xml-ancestors, 
                             descendants xml-descendants})
```

Answer (score 18):

```
(ns foo
  (:require [clojure.data.zip :refer [ancestors descendants] :rename {ancestors xml-ancestors descendants xml-descendants}]))
```

Answer (score 13):

You `:require` in one step, and then `:refer` with `:rename` in the next.

```
(ns foo
  (:require clojure.data.zip)
  (:refer [clojure.data.zip :rename {ancestors xml-ancestors,
                                     descendants xml-descendants})
```

`:use` has always been a shorthand for `:require`+`:refer`, and now the `:refer` option to `:require` is a shorthand for the simplest kind of `refer`.

Comment: Using `:rename` directly after `:refer` as @user1338062 suggests in his/her answer works and is easier: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27122360/100215

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer:  I do not know the "recommended" way to do this.  I only know how I would do it.  My solution may not be idiomatic Clojure, and I would be surprised if nobody came along with a better answer.

---

Here's what I would do: `:require` the package and alias it using `:as`:

```
(ns some.big.name.space
  (:require [clojure.data.zip  :as  cdz])
  ... some more imports, maybe ...)
```

Then the symbols can be accessed using the specified prefix, and don't conflict with any symbols in my `some.big.name.space` namespace:

```
(def some-list [cdz/ancestors cdz/descendants ancestors descendants])
```

If the alias is short, it hardly bothers me to type it, and I feel that my code is clearer -- the `cdz/` is a nice visual cue that the symbol is an import.

I know that this doesn't really answer your exact question -- how to use `:rename` with `:require` -- but I feel that it's worth mentioning because it avoids polluting my namespaces and I don't have to mess with Clojure's symbol resolution mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks for response. You are making a very good points. I am aware of this approach, just was curious how I do rename if I want to

Comment: @apolenur yes, sorry my answer wasn't more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to rename functions or macros from Clojure core use this:

```
(ns foo
  "Contains foo functionality."
  (:refer-clojure :rename {map core-map}))
```