# Simplest possible Clojure object that can accept a primitive and metadata?

Tags: clojure, metadata

I want to add metadata to a byte array in Clojure. Since this is not allowed, one option I want to try is the simplest object wrapper that could work.

Here is the source code for [with-meta](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L207).

That made me start looking at `Clojure.lang.IObj`. I haven't found what I want yet.

Comment: Have you looked at [`clojure.lang.Obj`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/1.5.x/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Obj.java)?

Comment: @DaoWen Yes, I have. I'm building up an example; I'll share if it has any promise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how you can create a [`deftype`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/deftype) that supports metadata.

```
(import '(java.io Writer))

(deftype Box [value _meta]
  clojure.lang.IObj
  (meta [_] _meta)
  (withMeta [_ m] (Box. value m))
  clojure.lang.IDeref
  (deref [_] value)
  Object
  (toString [this]
    (str (.getName (class this))
         ": "
         (pr-str value))))

(defmethod print-method Box [o, ^Writer w]
  (.write w "#<")
  (.write w (.getName (class o)))
  (.write w ": ")
  (.write w (-> o deref pr-str))
  (.write w ">"))

(defn box
  ([value] (box value nil))
  ([value meta] (Box. value meta)))
```

And here's some example usage:

```
user> (def boxed (box (->> (range 5)
                        (map byte)
                        (byte-array))
                      {:stuff :foo}))
#<Var@1acd39b: #<Box@c50aa1: #>>
user> @boxed
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
user> (meta boxed)
{:stuff :foo}
user> (meta (with-meta boxed {:stuff :bar}))
{:stuff :bar}
```

This is the simplest way I can think of to put metadata on a byte array (`reify` doesn't work with `clojure.lang.IObj` and records include more unrelated functionality).

Another option (and perhaps simpler depending on the context) would be to store the byte array in a map, with the metadata either right alongside it or as actual metadata.

Comment: Yes, `deftype` is more compact than writing a Java class by hand. A few comments. Clojure stores empty metadata as `nil`, not `{}`. Also, implementing `toString` would be nice.

Comment: @DavidJames, I added simple `toString` and `print-method` implementations, and changed the default metadata from `{}` to `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

After discussing with some people on #clojure IRC, I wrote a simple Java class, `MetaBox`, that implements `clojure.lang.IObj`. You can use this easily in Clojure with `metabox/box` and `metabox/val` as well as the usual metadata functions such as `meta` and `with-meta`.

```
; [metabox "0.1.0"]
(require '[metabox.core :refer (box val)])
(def critical-density (box 0.692 {:uncertainty 0.01}))
(val critical-density) ; 0.692
(meta critical-density) ; {:uncertainty 0.01}
```

You can find the source code and README over at [clj-metabox](https://github.com/bluemont/clj-metabox).

UPDATE: Thanks to a few discussions and suggestion (see below), as of [version 0.2.0](https://clojars.org/metabox/versions/0.2.0), the API uses `deref` instead of `val`:

```
; [metabox "0.2.0"]
(require '[metabox.core :refer (box)])
(def critical-density (box 0.692 {:uncertainty 0.01}))
@critical-density ; 0.692
(meta critical-density) ; {:uncertainty 0.01}
```

Comment: What considerations lead you to choose this over a `deftype`? Btw, since without a prefix `val` would shadow `clojure.core/val` it might be worth using something else (`value` or `val-of` maybe?)

Comment: Actually, `clojure.lang.IDeref` might be a great way to expose the value. I updated my example code to include that (and adopted the term `box`).

Comment: jbm: We just had a discussion about the reference types on IRC. That's an interesting idea -- and the `deref` / `@` syntax is clean and tempting. However, the reference types have too much baked in for my particular use case. Clojure has them to manage state and identity. I simply need immutability; I don't need or want the boxed value to be settable or changeable in the ways that refs, agents, or agents provide. I don't want to defer or shift computation like delays or futures or promises do.

Comment: Deftype doesn't create a reference type - it essentially generates a Java class (see [here](http://clojure.org/datatypes) for details). Agents, futures, etc. are unrelated to my suggestion other than that they happen to expose various functionality via `IDeref`. Also, while deftypes *can* have mutable fields (as Java classes can), by default they do not (and my example doesn't). Basically I think you may be misunderstanding deftype :)

Comment: @jbm: My comments above about reference types were in regards to `clojure.lang.IDeref`.

Comment: @jbm: `deftype` is a fine way to go and may be better in some ways; e.g. ClojureScript interop. I just happened to write the Java class in my example.

Comment: The examples use `box` and `val` for brevity; feel free to use `metabox/val` if you prefer that. The library does not impose shadowing; it is up to your code to decide how you want to refer to those functions.

Comment: Cool; I was wondering in part because I don't know much about primitives. Not to drag this on, but w.r.t `IDeref`: using it to expose the value doesn't bake in any of the reference types' functionality. However, I can see why you might want to avoid it on semantic grounds (that's how it's normally used so you don't want to overload the concept), which is a valid point.

Comment: Yeah, I get namespacing, but sometimes it's still convenient to avoid common `clojure.core` names unless there's a reasonably strong reason why that's the "right" name. `val` is nice and short, but if everyone uses `b/val` or `box/val` then maybe `value` would actually be more convenient (and no less meaningful). Clearly there's no right answer here, I was just offering my $0.02.

Comment: jbm: That's a good point that `clojure.lang.IDeref` is minimal. The source code is `public interface IDeref { Object deref(); }`. It doesn't have `setValidator`, `getValidator`, `getWatches`, `addWatch`, and `removeWatch` like `clojure.lang.IRef` does. Still, the act of 'dereferencing' implies a 'reference', doesn't it? Put another way, do you know of any Clojure class/type that supports dereferencing that is *not* a reference type?

Comment: @jbm Re: namespacing... pleasing everyone is hard. :) I'm the first (and possibly only) user, so I'll keep it as is for now. Luckily, you can `:rename` `val` if you prefer, using a less commonly-known feature: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14614390/109618

Comment: Well, [Reduced](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Reduced.java) doesn't seem any more reference-y than `Box`, but I agree that de-referencing applies a reference. (The reason I thought of `IDeref` to begin with is that boxing a value adds a level of indirection *vaguely* similar to e.g. a `Var`). In a plain-English sense a `Box` is a reference to a value and its metadata, despite not having the state/identity features of Clojure's reference types. (And now I'm going to stop spamming your question and go to bed :)

Comment: The `future` macro returns derefable objects (`deref` on a future returns its value, blocking until it's ready). As @jbm pointed out, so does `reduced`. Given these two examples from core, I don't think implementing `IDeref` necessarily implies anything beyond usability with `deref` / `@` at this point. Additionally, a box *is* a reified reference (possibly with extra functionality, although it's not a given, for example `clojure.lang.Box` is used for out-of-band returns).

Comment: I should add that I'm not saying that hooking into `deref` is a must or that there's anything wrong with providing a new function instead; I just think it makes sense to hook into `deref` given its usage in `clojure.lang` & `clojure.core` and the intended function of `MetaBox`. Basically I wanted to add my €0.02 in support of @jbm's position (including the "Clearly there's no right answer here" part ;-)).

Comment: What do you mean by "reference type"?  Of course, implementing `IDeref` makes a type a "reference type" for some definition of "reference type", but merely using a different function for dereferencing doesn't necessarily make a type any less of a "reference type".

Comment: Also, for further examples of immutable reference types found in core, there's also `delay` and `promise`.