# add metadata to a Java Object in clojure

Tags: clojure, metadata

I am working with a Java library in clojure and I would like to attach some extra information to those objects while I do stuff to them. I was thinking of stashing the info as metadata although I'm not committed to that and if you have any better suggestions, I would love to hear them.

The basic example would be to add a name to a `BufferedImage` and store it as metadata. The goal is to process the image and then be able to pull the name back out.

```
(ns test.clj
  (:import [java.awt BufferedImage]))

; define a new image and try to attach data    
(let [image (new BufferedImage 200 200 1)]
  (with-meta image {:name "myawesomepicture"}))

;generates the following error
  ;ClassCastException java.awt.image.BufferedImage 
  ;cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IObj    
  ;clojure.core/with-meta (core.clj:214)
```

There is a recent post that defines a type that can [attach metadata to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20724219/simplest-possible-clojure-object-that-can-accept-a-primitive-and-metadata) but this wraps the values which will trigger type errors when trying to use the object as shown below. (`box` is a metadata wrapping function from the previous link; `show` is a function from mikera's [imagez](https://github.com/mikera/imagez/) library that displays a BufferedImage).

```
(use 'mikera.image.core)
(def image1 (new BufferedImage 200 200 1))
(show image1) ; no problem
(def image2 (box image1 {:name "test"})) ; add metadata using box wrapper function
(show image2) ; ClassCastException Box cannot be cast to java.awt.image.BufferedImage
```

I would appreciate any thoughts on using clojure to tag Java objects with custom data  - whether as metadata or fields or whatever.

thanks,
zach cp

Comment: Make a type which extends BufferedImage. The new type should implement IObj. See: https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/extend

Comment: Also: http://clojure.org/multimethods